# How to use bundles to exchange data between 2 Fragments in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way in which we can pass pass data through bundles from one fragment to another in Android 3.0. If yes, what is the procedure of exchanging data through bundles in fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you would exchange a bundle between any two other classes.

Comment: Can u Explain Elaborately. What I mean is we use intents to pass bundle of data from one activity to other. But here in Fragments as we wont use intents, then how to pass bundle data from one fragment to other,.